# What is the reason to have LOC/VNAV landing method?

Tags: landing, localizer, rnav

What is purpose of mixing LOC/VNAV in this landing method?

Comment: The purpose is landing, could you be a bit more specific with your question?

Comment: There are many landing modes (FLS, ILS, MLS etc..)  but when will we use Mix LOC/VNAV landing method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A VNAV with localiser approach is normally a backup to a regular ILS should there be a glide slope unserviceability. The use of VNAV  to manage the vertical portion of the approach would allow the use of APV minima which are normally lower than using a vertical speed mode.

VNAV is a better mode when conducting non-precision approaches as the aircraft is still following a defined glideslope - albeit derived from a database - which is more accurate than trying to follow a tabled set of heights and distances using vertical speed.